# How to run multiple server labels on same port using node and hapi?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I am trying to host api and web servers on the same node code stack. I have used labels in order to apply configurations independently to each server but only one server works. Below is the code:

```
var hapi = require('hapi');

// server definition
var server = new hapi.Server();
var runningPort = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// setting up connection
server.connection({
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: runningPort,
    labels: ['api']
});

server.connection({
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: runningPort,
    labels: ['web']
});



var webServer = server.select('web');
var apiServer = server.select('api');

// registering view engine
webServer.views({
    engines: { html: require('handlebars') },
    relativeTo: __dirname,
    path: './views',
    layoutPath: './views/layout',
    layout: 'default',
    partialsPath: './views/partials'
});

// registering hapi auth cookie and application authentication
webServer.register(
  {
    register: require('hapi-auth-cookie')
  }, 
  function (err) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    var cache = webServer.cache({ segment: 'sessions', expiresIn: 3 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 });
    webServer.app.cache = cache;

    webServer.auth.strategy('session', 'cookie', true, {
        password: 'secret',
        cookie: 'sid-example',
        redirectTo: '/account/login',
        isSecure: false
    });
});

// registrations for api server
apiServer.register(
        {
            register: require('lout')
        },
    function (err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
});

apiServer.register(require('hapi-auth-bearer-token'), function (err) {

    apiServer.auth.strategy('simple', 'bearer-access-token', {
        allowQueryToken: true,              // optional, true by default
        allowMultipleHeaders: false,        // optional, false by default
        accessTokenName: 'access_token',    // optional, 'access_token' by default
        validateFunc: function( token, callback ) {

            // For convenience, the request object can be accessed
            // from `this` within validateFunc.
            var request = this;

            // Use a real strategy here,
            // comparing with a token from your database for example
            if(token === "1234"){
                //## user object to be looked up here
                callback(null, true, { token: token })
            } else {
                callback(null, false, { token: token })
            }
        }
    });
});

//To do something to request before they passed on to routes
apiServer.ext('onRequest', function (request, reply) {
    //## we can get user object here off of the authToken
    utils.log('info', 'apiCall', {method: request.method, path: request.path})
    return reply.continue();
});

// register routes
webServer.route(webRoutes);
apiServer.route(apiRoutes);

server.start(function () {
    console.log('Web servers running at: ', 'localhost:' + runningPort);
    console.log('Api server running at: ', 'localhost:' + runningPort);
});
```

Currently only api routes work.

Comment: Looks to me like you're trying to run the API and the web server on the same port. That'll get you a port conflict. Try changing the port?

Comment: You can't start two servers on the same port. Just set a different one for each and it will work fine.

Comment: and what about the server? run em on 2 different ports?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the commenters, you can't create 2 connections to the same port on the same network interface. This goes all the way back to the [listen syscall](http://linux.die.net/man/2/listen) giving a EADDRINUSE error if two sockets try to listen on the same port.

Creating two connections on separate ports or separate network interfaces is perfectly ok though:

```
server.connection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 4000,
    labels: ['api']
});

server.connection({
    host: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 4001,
    labels: ['web']
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As Matt already said, you can't run different connections on the same port. Make sure to apply different ports, like

```
server.connection({  
    host: 'localhost',
    port: process.env.PORT || port
});

server.connection({  
    host: 'localhost',
    port: process.env.PORT + 1 || port + 1
});
```

If you want to read more on running an API and your web server within the same hapi project, you might scan through those tutorials:

- https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-how-to-run-separate-frontend-and-backend-servers-within-one-project
- https://futurestud.io/tutorials/hapi-how-to-use-server-labels

Hope that helps!